# How to recover ParseTree of antlr4 to source

Tags: antlr4

I had build a ParseTree with antlr4 for analyse SQL, but how can I recover a ParseTree object to it source?

Such as I analyse the SQL to tree:

```
select a from (select 1 from tab);
```

I extract the sub query and want to convert it to sql like this:

```
select 1 from tab
```

I know write a function to retrieve the tree can recover the tree to source, but I want to know whether ANTLR4 has the function now?

Thanks!